# How to load child named routes in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

My Route config is:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: WelcomeComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {path: 'app',pathMatch: 'full',component:MainChatComponent,
        children: [
          {path: '', component: ChatListComponent, outlet: 'leftPanel'},
          {path: 'profile', component: EditProfileComponent, outlet: 'leftPanel', pathMatch: 'full'},

          {path: '', component: ChatComponent, outlet: 'mainPanel'},
          {path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent, outlet: 'mainPanel', pathMatch: 'full'}
        ]
      },
      {path: '404', component: WelcomeComponent,pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: '**', redirectTo: 'app'}
    ];
```

MainChatComponent Template is:

```
<div class="row match-parent margin-0">
  <div class="col-lg-3 left-panel app-panel match-parent padding-0" style="background: #f7f7f7;">
    <router-outlet name="leftPanel"></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9 center-panel app-panel match-parent padding-0">
    <router-outlet name="mainPanel"></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is that i am unable to load "profile" & "welcome" paths in their respective outlets which is present under the children's of "app"

Comment: You cannot load profile and welcome at the same time with this route configuration

Comment: @younesm so how can i achieve this

Comment: Besides, it seems likes you are using routes only to load components. Keep in mind that components loaded by routes are bound to the URI. You can load components without using routes by using their selectors.

Comment: We need more details to answer, what's the route you want your components to load in  ?

Comment: @YounesM actually i need to load it when i click item in ChatListComponent, it should replace messages view with WelcomeComponent in mainPanel

Comment: Is there a reason you're using router outlets instead of selectors ? Can't you just replace your outlets respectively by `<chat-list></chat-list>` and `<welcome></welcome>` ?

Comment: @YounesM actually i cant use selectors because i need to replace that specific outlet with different components that i am going to add. this is why i can't use selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `<router-outlets>` to load components that are layouts.

You can achieve what you're trying to do by using the selectors and templates below :

```
 const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: WelcomeComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {path: 'app',pathMatch: 'full',component:MainChatComponent,
        children: [
          {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
          {path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent, outlet: 'mainPanel', pathMatch: 'full'}
        ]
      },
      {path: '404', component: WelcomeComponent,pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: '**', redirectTo: 'app'}
    ];
```

profile.component.html

```
<div class="row match-parent margin-0">
  <div class="col-lg-3 left-panel app-panel match-parent padding-0" style="background: #f7f7f7;">
    <app-chat-list></app-chat-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9 center-panel app-panel match-parent padding-0">
    <app-edit-profile></app-edit-profile>
  </div>
</div>
```

welcome.component.html

```
<div class="row match-parent margin-0">
  <div class="col-lg-3 left-panel app-panel match-parent padding-0" style="background: #f7f7f7;">
    <app-chat></app-chat>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9 center-panel app-panel match-parent padding-0">
    <app-welcome></app-welcome>
  </div>
</div>
```

main.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```